# Replace hintText with predefined list

Tags: javascript, jquery, tokenize

I'm working on a project using [jQuery Tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/). The plugin is described as such:

> Tokeninput is a jQuery plugin which allows your users to select multiple items from a predefined list, using autocompletion as they
>   type to find each item.

See a working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/WGmrr/

Is there a way that I can show the entire predefined list once the user clicks the inputbox but before the user starts typing, effectively replacing the `hintText` that reads `Type in a search term`?

Comment: Probably, but why would you want to?

Comment: I hope your clients (with e-mails listed) are warned that you are publicly sharing their contacts.

Comment: @mblase75 There is a decent use case for this, but not within Tokeninput. Chosen does this quite effectively.

Comment: @roXon - they're all bogus contacts; please see [this](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/demo.html).

Comment: @Wex ... well... `adriana.jameson@gmail.com` looks terribly real ;)

Comment: @mblase75 - the way I see it, there are two cases. Either the user knows what they want, so they make use of the autocomplete feature, or they don't know what they want, and have the ability to search through a predefined list.

Comment: @Wex But if the list is short enough to scroll through, then you don't need autocomplete; and if the list is long enough to justify autocomplete, then it's too long to scroll through. Depending on how many names you have, you'd either use one or the other, but there's no good reason to need both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an entirely different UX approach here and go with **Harvest's [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) plugin**, using `Multiple Select`:

[image: Chosen screenshot]

It looks wonderful, works well, and can be re-used in different contexts.

Comment: Thanks for this link, I'll definitely look into it. If I can't get an answer that helps me with the plugin I'm already using, I'll certainly use this.

Comment: @Wex If you're easily swayed by big boys using cool stuff, GitHub uses Chosen. Go to https://gist.github.com/ and select the language.